# WPF Create a reuseable UserControl that binds to ObservableCollection<float>

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am trying to creare a reusable UserControl that can edit an ObservableCollection
this what i got:
[image]

The problem is the values insdie the array wont update from the UI, or from the property (code).

i got the textboxes to shows, but changing value from UI wont update the property collection.

**i want to avoid wrapping the floats with a class.**

this is what i got :
UserControl.xaml:

```
 <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Silver" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=textboxesUserControl}">
     <StackPanel>

         <WrapPanel>
             <Label Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NumberOfTextBoxs}}, Path=MainLabel}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
             <Button Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NumberOfTextBoxs}}, Path=ShowAllButton,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" 
             Content="All"
             HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Click="Button_Click"/>
         </WrapPanel>
         <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PreviewMouseWheel="ScrollViewer_PreviewMouseWheel" CanContentScroll="True" PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" Background="Transparent" >

             <WrapPanel >



                 <ItemsControl x:Name="items"  AlternationCount="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NumberOfTextBoxs}},Path=NumberOfTextBoxes}">
                     <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                         <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LimitListToCountConvertor}" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                             <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NumberOfTextBoxs}}" Path="Values" />
                             <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:NumberOfTextBoxs}}" Path="NumberOfTextBoxes" />
                             
                         </MultiBinding>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                     <ItemsControl.Resources>
                         <domain:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding }" />
                     </ItemsControl.Resources>
                     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <Border Margin="1" BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" >
                                 <TextBox  md:ValidationAssist.UsePopup="True"  md:HintAssist.Hint="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, StringFormat={}{0}:,Converter={StaticResource math},ConverterParameter=x+1}" MaxWidth="80"  Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}"  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                     <TextBox.Text>
                                             <Binding  Path="." UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" NotifyOnValidationError="True" Mode="TwoWay">
                                                 <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                                     <domain:RangeValidtaions  ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True">
                                                         <domain:RangeValidtaions.WrapperMinMax>
                                                             <domain:Wrapper Min="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.Min,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                                   Max="{Binding Source={StaticResource proxy}, Path=Data.Max,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                                         </domain:RangeValidtaions.WrapperMinMax>
                                                     </domain:RangeValidtaions>
                                                 </Binding.ValidationRules>
                                             </Binding>
                                         </TextBox.Text>
                                     </TextBox>
                                
                             </Border>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                             <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="true"/>
                         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                 </ItemsControl>
             </WrapPanel>
         </ScrollViewer>
     </StackPanel>
 </Border>
```

UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty NumOfTextBoxes = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(NumberOfTextBoxes), propertyType: typeof(int), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue: 1,changed));
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MinDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(Min), propertyType: typeof(float), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue: 0f));
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(Max), propertyType: typeof(float), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue: 1f));
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowAllButtonDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(ShowAllButton), propertyType: typeof(bool), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue: true));
  public static readonly DependencyProperty MainLabelDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(MainLabel), propertyType: typeof(string), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(defaultValue: ""));
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValuesDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(Values), propertyType: typeof(ObservableCollection<float>), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<float>()));

  private static void changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(CommandAllButton), propertyType: typeof(ICommand), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());
  public static readonly DependencyProperty ValidatorDp = DependencyProperty.Register(name: nameof(VadlitionCmd), propertyType: typeof(ICommand), ownerType: typeof(NumberOfTextBoxs), typeMetadata: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());



  public int NumberOfTextBoxes
  {
      get => (int)GetValue(NumOfTextBoxes);
      set => SetValue(NumOfTextBoxes, value);
  }
  public float Min
  {
      get => (int)GetValue(MinDp);
      set => SetValue(MinDp, value);
  }
  public float Max
  {
      get => (float)GetValue(MaxDp);
      set => SetValue(MaxDp, value);
  }
  public bool ShowAllButton
  {
      get => (bool)GetValue(ShowAllButtonDp);
      set => SetValue(ShowAllButtonDp, value);
  }
  public string MainLabel
  {
      get => (string)GetValue(MainLabelDp);
      set => SetValue(MainLabelDp, value);
  }
  public ObservableCollection<float> Values
  {
      get => ((ObservableCollection<float>)GetValue(ValuesDp));
      set => SetValue(ValuesDp, value);
  }
  public ICommand CommandAllButton
  {
      get => (ICommand)GetValue(CommandDp);
      set => SetValue(CommandDp, value);
  }
  public ICommand VadlitionCmd
  {
      get => (ICommand)GetValue(ValidatorDp);
      set => SetValue(ValidatorDp, value);
  }
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<utils:NumberOfTextBoxs Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"  NumberOfTextBoxes="{Binding MaxTextBoxes}" Min="0" Max="0.99"  MainLabel="Test:" Values="{Binding GainsValues}"/>
```

**EDIT:**
I've ended up with creating a middle man in the UserControl.xaml.cs
That convret the ObservableCollection to a ObservableCollection>, and vice-versa.

Comment: Use BindingList instead. ObservableCollection, "observes" only Add/Remove/etc operations. It will ignore if element is notifiable, nor your float is notifiable. Create notifiable wrapper around float if you want to edit it, then use BindingList, then any changes be it Add/Remove or element update - will change your view and visa-versa.